# Single tab multiple content bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on bootstrap tabs, I am trying for the single tab with multiple content div's. I have tried by using two data-target values like `data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1"`.but it only works for one content div other second content is not changing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTab a').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href == "[href^='tab-']") {
      $('.tab-pane').css('display', 'none');
      $("[class^='etab-'][class^='etabi-']").removeClass('show');
      $("[class^='etab-'][class^='etabi-']").css('display', 'block');
      $("[class^='etab-'][class^='etabi-']").addClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1" data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" data-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" data-target=".etab-p3, .etabi-img3" data-toggle="tab">C3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" data-target=".etab-p4, .etabi-img4" data-toggle="tab">C4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" data-target=".etab-p5, .etabi-img5" data-toggle="tab">C5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-6" data-target=".etab-p6, .etabi-img6" data-toggle="tab">C6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etab-p1">
    <p>Content 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p2">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p3">
    <p>Content 3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p4">
    <p>Content 4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p5">
    <p>Content 5.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p6">
    <p>Content 6.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etabi-img1">
    <p>Content 111.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img2">
    <p>Content 2222.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img3">
    <p>Content 3333.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img4">
    <p>Content 4444.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img5">
    <p>Content 5555.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img6">
    <p>Content 6666.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to work as a fiddle and 2 you mention i have two tabs does that means you already have two tabs and want two more.

Comment: @NickCoder Actually I have tried with multiple ways but unable to achieve the desired output that is why if anyone post fiddle it will help to understand the code and shows it will work fine.

Comment: so what you want and correct me if i am wrong you want simple working two tabs and content should change by tab clicks right

Comment: @NickCoder simple two tabs working on the same page and each tab having two content div when click on tab two div's have to change

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with bootstrap 4 tab only or any other way is fine with you?

Comment: @SumitPatel Any other way also fine.

Comment: I just posted the answer please check and let me know if that work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`show.bs.tab`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events) event

```js
$('#myTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
  let target = $(e.target).data('target');
  $(target)
    .addClass('active show')
    .siblings('.tab-pane.active')
    .removeClass('active show')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active show" href="#tab-1" data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" data-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" data-target=".etab-p3, .etabi-img3" data-toggle="tab">C3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" data-target=".etab-p4, .etabi-img4" data-toggle="tab">C4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" data-target=".etab-p5, .etabi-img5" data-toggle="tab">C5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-6" data-target=".etab-p6, .etabi-img6" data-toggle="tab">C6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etab-p1">
    <p>Content 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p2">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p3">
    <p>Content 3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p4">
    <p>Content 4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p5">
    <p>Content 5.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p6">
    <p>Content 6.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etabi-img1">
    <p>Content 111.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img2">
    <p>Content 2222.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img3">
    <p>Content 3333.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img4">
    <p>Content 4444.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img5">
    <p>Content 5555.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img6">
    <p>Content 6666.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#myTab a').click(function(){
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(href == "#profile") {
   $('.profile, .profile_else').css('display','')
   $('.profile, .profile_else').addClass('show')
    $('.profile, .profile_else').removeClass('hide')
    $('.home, .home_else').removeClass('show')
    $('.home, .home_else').addClass('hide')
  }
  if(href == "#home") {
  $('.home, .home_else').addClass('show')
    $('.home, .home_else').removeClass('hide')
   $('.home, .home_else').css('display','')
    $('.profile, .profile_else').removeClass('show')
    $('.profile, .profile_else').addClass('hide')
  }
})
})
```

```css
body {
    padding:70px;
}
.tab-content{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.show{
 display: block !important;
}
.hide{
  display: none !important;
}
.nav-link.active{
  background-color: red !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#home" data-target=".home, .home_else" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#profile" data-target=".profile, .profile_else" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show home">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade hide profile">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show home_else">
        <p>Content 111.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade hide profile_else">
        <p>Content 2222.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

use only id don't use more than one id in data-target.
Add multiple content div inside single tab div.

Comment: I have updated my question for better understanding now check it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#tabcontainer .tabs').hide().eq(0).show();
    $('#tabcontainer-2 .tabs').hide().eq(0).show();
    $('#tabs li').click(function(){
        num = $('#tabs li').index(this);
        $('#tabcontainer .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
        $('#tabcontainer-2 .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
    });
});
```

```css
#tabs li {list-style: none; background:#ccc; padding: 10px;}
#tabcontainer-2{
    width:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#tabcontainer{
    width:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul li{
    width:75px;
    float:left;
    position relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul><br/><br/><br/><br/>
 
 <div id="tabcontainer">
  <div id="tabcontent1" class="tabs">Content1 from link 1</div>
  <div id="tabcontent2" class="tabs">Content1 from link 2</div>
  <div id="tabcontent3" class="tabs">Content1 from link 3</div>
  <div id="tabcontent4" class="tabs">Content1 from link 4</div> 
 </div>
 
 <div id="tabcontainer-2">
  <div id="tabcontent1-2" class="tabs">Content2 from link 1</div>
  <div id="tabcontent2-2" class="tabs">Content2 from link 2</div>
  <div id="tabcontent3-3" class="tabs">Content2 from link 3</div>
  <div id="tabcontent4-4" class="tabs">Content2 from link 4</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple tab provided by bootstrap itself.
please take a look. this one is sample which I used in my project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
    var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p style='color:pink'>I am working on bootstrap tabs, I am trying for the single tab with multiple content div's. I have tried by using two data-target values like data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1".but it only works for ..</p>
       <p style='color:green'>I am working on bootstrap tabs, I am trying for the single tab with multiple content div's. I have tried by using two data-target values like data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1".but it only works for ..</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p style='color:red;'>Tab based navigations provides an easy and powerful mechanism to handle huge amount of content within a small area through separating content into different panes where each pane is viewable one at a time. The user can quickly access the content through switching between the panes without leaving the page. The following example will show you how to create the basic tabs using the Bootstrap tab component.</p>
      <p style='color:green;'>Tab based navigations provides an easy and powerful mechanism to handle huge amount of content within a small area through separating content into different panes where each pane is viewable one at a time. The user can quickly access the content through switching between the panes without leaving the page. The following example will show you how to create the basic tabs using the Bootstrap tab component.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p style='color:green;'> This event fires after the previous active tab is hidden and a new tab is shown. You can use the event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the previous active tab and the new active tab, respectively. This event fires after the previous active tab is hidden and a new tab is shown. You can use the event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the previous active tab and the new active tab, respectively..</p>
         <p style='color:red;'> This event fires after the previous active tab is hidden and a new tab is shown. You can use the event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the previous active tab and the new active tab, respectively. This event fires after the previous active tab is hidden and a new tab is shown. You can use the event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the previous active tab and the new active tab, respectively..</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p style='color:blue'>You can activate a tab component without writing any JavaScript — simply specify the data-toggle="tab" on each tab, as well as create a .tab-pane with unique ID for every tab and wrap them in .tab-content. The following example will show you how to create a basic tabbable tabs via data attributes in Bootstrap.</p>
        <p style='color:cyan'>You can activate a tab component without writing any JavaScript — simply specify the data-toggle="tab" on each tab, as well as create a .tab-pane with unique ID for every tab and wrap them in .tab-content. The following example will show you how to create a basic tabbable tabs via data attributes in Bootstrap.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="act"><b>Active Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
    <p class="prev"><b>Previous Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                Content 1
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                Another Content 1
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="container hide">
      <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                Content 2
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                Another Content 2
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @R oV what if  ` Another Content 1`  is in the other div. here you are doing in the same parent div with the same id.

Comment: iam sorry, mistakenly I delete my previous code snippet. Just add the javascript function and put the 'Another Content 1' div outside the `tab-content` div

Comment: @R oV Still not working can you please post a snippet of your code.

Comment: @Husna I updated my answer, comment if its the answer or not, would like to help more ;)

Comment: @R oV you didn't understand what I'm trying to explain to you. The content div is in different places on page totally two different blocks ex: one content in the header and then second content in the footer like this  I'm trying to change those blocks.using id and href

Answer (score 0):

here is a code snippet that will help you with your question :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1" role="tab">First Panel</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2" role="tab">Second Panel</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" role="tab">Third Panel</a>
 </li>
</ul><!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel">
  <div>First Panel div1</div>
  <div>First Panel div2</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel">
  <div>Second Panel div1</div>
  <div>Second Panel div2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel">
  <p>Second Panel duv2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3" role="tabpanel">
  <p>Third Panel</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem using jquery.

Here is the solution :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTab a').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var num = href.split("-")[1];
      $('.tab-pane').css('display', 'none');
      $("[class^='etab-'][class^='etabi-']").removeClass('show');
      $(".etab-p"+num).css('display', 'block');
      $(".etabi-img"+num).css('display', 'block');
      $(".etab-p"+num).addClass('show');
      $(".etabi-img"+num).addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:70px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1" data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" data-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" data-target=".etab-p3, .etabi-img3" data-toggle="tab">C3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" data-target=".etab-p4, .etabi-img4" data-toggle="tab">C4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" data-target=".etab-p5, .etabi-img5" data-toggle="tab">C5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-6" data-target=".etab-p6, .etabi-img6" data-toggle="tab">C6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etab-p1">
    <p>Content 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p2">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p3">
    <p>Content 3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p4">
    <p>Content 4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p5">
    <p>Content 5.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p6">
    <p>Content 6.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etabi-img1">
    <p>Content 111.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img2">
    <p>Content 2222.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img3">
    <p>Content 3333.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img4">
    <p>Content 4444.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img5">
    <p>Content 5555.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img6">
    <p>Content 6666.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I had gone through this link previously the problem is cdn non-standard once check it

Comment: @Husna Have you checked new fiddle?[link](http://jsfiddle.net/g4k8mb6y/)

Comment: I have updated my question for better understanding now check it.

Comment: @Husna Please try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32fbhdpv/1/) and let me know it works or not.

Comment: @Husna I have also edited the answer and added snippet. Please check and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Purojit i want to add some animation.

Comment: @Husna which type of animation you want ?

Comment: I got the animation.

Comment: @Husna Great bro

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @User863 for the answer using Bootstrap 4. For anyone that might come across this today using Bootstrap 5.1.3, here's an updated and simplified example:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active show" data-bs-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-bs-toggle="tab">C1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-bs-toggle="tab">C2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active etab-p1">
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p2">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active etabi-img1">
        <p>Content 111.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img2">
        <p>Content 2222.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#myTab a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        let target = $(e.target).data('bs-target');
        $(target)
            .addClass('active show')
            .siblings('.tab-pane.active')
            .removeClass('active show')
    });
</script>
```